# minted package doesn't work in XeLaTeX but works well in PdfLaTeX

Tags: pdftex, xetex, compiling, minted, windows

I'm trying to use the `minted` package in my new computer. My tex code is as follows, and I'm using MikTeX + TexMaker in Windows 10:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[cache=false]{minted}
\begin{document}
First Line
\begin{minted}{python}
import numpy as np
\end{minted}
Second Line
\end{document}
```

In XeLaTeX, the compilation command line is `"xelatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape %.tex"`, the output result doesn't show the expected highlighted Python code:

[image]

And in PdfLaTeX, the compilation command line is `"pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape %.tex"` with the output result:

[image]

I want to use XeLaTeX, but don't know how to make it works. Any suggestion or hint?

P.S. The full content of log file:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999995 (MiKTeX 24.1) (preloaded format=xelatex 2024.3.23)  28 MAR 2024 15:33
entering extended mode
 \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**./test.tex
(test.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-01-04>
(D:\OfficeSoftware\MikTex\tex/latex/base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(D:\OfficeSoftware\MikTex\tex/latex/base\size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count183
\c@section=\count184
\c@subsection=\count185
\c@subsubsection=\count186
\c@paragraph=\count187
\c@subparagraph=\count188
\c@figure=\count189
\c@table=\count190
\abovecaptionskip=\skip48
\belowcaptionskip=\skip49
\bibindent=\dimen140
)
(D:\OfficeSoftware\MikTex\tex/latex/minted\minted.sty
Package: minted 2023/12/18 v2.9 Yet another Pygments shim for LaTeX

(D:\OfficeSoftware\MikTex\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks17
)
(D:\OfficeSoftware\MikTex\tex/latex/kvoptions\kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2022-06-15 v3.15 Key value format for package options (HO)

(D:\OfficeSoftware\MikTex\tex/generic/ltxcmds\ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2023-12-04 v1.26 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
(D:\OfficeSoftware\MikTex\tex/latex/kvsetkeys\kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2022-10-05 v1.19 Key value parser (HO)
))
(D:\OfficeSoftware\MikTex\tex/latex/fvextra\fvextra.sty
Package: fvextra 2023/11/28 v1.6.1 fvextra - extensions and patches for fancyvr
b

(D:\OfficeSoftware\MikTex\tex/latex/etoolbox\etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count191
)
(D:\OfficeSoftware\MikTex\tex/latex/fancyvrb\fancyvrb.sty
Package: fancyvrb 2024/01/20 4.5c verbatim text (tvz,hv)
\FV@CodeLineNo=\count192
\FV@InFile=\read2
\FV@TabBox=\box51
\c@FancyVerbLine=\count193
\FV@StepNumber=\count194
\FV@OutFile=\write3
)
(D:\OfficeSoftware\MikTex\tex/latex/upquote\upquote.sty
Package: upquote 2012/04/19 v1.3 upright-quote and grave-accent glyphs in verba
tim

(D:\OfficeSoftware\MikTex\tex/latex/base\textcomp.sty
Package: textcomp 2020/02/02 v2.0n Standard LaTeX package
))
(D:\OfficeSoftware\MikTex\tex/latex/lineno\lineno.sty
Package: lineno 2023/05/20 line numbers on paragraphs v5.3
Invalid UTF-8 byte or sequence at line 292 replaced by U+FFFD.
\linenopenalty=\count195
\output=\toks18
\linenoprevgraf=\count196
\linenumbersep=\dimen141
\linenumberwidth=\dimen142
\c@linenumber=\count197
\c@pagewiselinenumber=\count198
\c@LN@truepage=\count199
\c@internallinenumber=\count266
\c@internallinenumbers=\count267
\quotelinenumbersep=\dimen143
\bframerule=\dimen144
\bframesep=\dimen145
\bframebox=\box52
LaTeX Info: Redefining \\ on input line 3180.
)
\c@FancyVerbWriteLine=\count268
\c@FancyVerbBufferIndex=\count269
\c@FancyVerbBufferLength=\count270
\c@FancyVerbBufferLine=\count271
\c@FV@oldbufferlength=\count272
\c@FV@TrueTabGroupLevel=\count273
\c@FV@TrueTabCounter=\count274
\FV@TabBox@Group=\box53
\FV@TmpLength=\skip50
\c@FV@HighlightLinesStart=\count275
\c@FV@HighlightLinesStop=\count276
\FV@LoopCount=\count277
\FV@NCharsBox=\box54
\FV@BreakIndent=\dimen146
\FV@BreakIndentNChars=\count278
\FV@BreakSymbolSepLeft=\dimen147
\FV@BreakSymbolSepLeftNChars=\count279
\FV@BreakSymbolSepRight=\dimen148
\FV@BreakSymbolSepRightNChars=\count280
\FV@BreakSymbolIndentLeft=\dimen149
\FV@BreakSymbolIndentLeftNChars=\count281
\FV@BreakSymbolIndentRight=\dimen150
\FV@BreakSymbolIndentRightNChars=\count282
\c@FancyVerbLineBreakLast=\count283
\FV@LineBox=\box55
\FV@LineIndentBox=\box56
\c@FV@BreakBufferDepth=\count284
\FV@LineWidth=\dimen151
)
(D:\OfficeSoftware\MikTex\tex/latex/base\ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2022/04/13 v1.1d Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
(D:\OfficeSoftware\MikTex\tex/latex/tools\shellesc.sty
Package: shellesc 2023/07/08 v1.0d unified shell escape interface for LaTeX
Package shellesc Info: Unrestricted shell escape enabled on input line 75.
)
(D:\OfficeSoftware\MikTex\tex/latex/ifplatform\ifplatform.sty
Package: ifplatform 2017/10/13 v0.4a Testing for the operating system

(D:\OfficeSoftware\MikTex\tex/generic/pdftexcmds\pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)

(D:\OfficeSoftware\MikTex\tex/generic/infwarerr\infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
(D:\OfficeSoftware\MikTex\tex/generic/iftex\iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2022/02/03 v1.0f TeX engine tests
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode not found.
)
(D:\OfficeSoftware\MikTex\tex/generic/catchfile\catchfile.sty
Package: catchfile 2019/12/09 v1.8 Catch the contents of a file (HO)

(D:\OfficeSoftware\MikTex\tex/generic/etexcmds\etexcmds.sty
Package: etexcmds 2019/12/15 v1.7 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
))
(D:\OfficeSoftware\MikTex\tex/generic/iftex\ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2019/10/25 v1.5 ifluatex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
))
(D:\OfficeSoftware\MikTex\tex/latex/xstring\xstring.sty
(D:\OfficeSoftware\MikTex\tex/generic/xstring\xstring.tex
\xs_counta=\count285
\xs_countb=\count286
)
Package: xstring 2023/08/22 v1.86 String manipulations (CT)
)
(D:\OfficeSoftware\MikTex\tex/latex/framed\framed.sty
Package: framed 2011/10/22 v 0.96: framed or shaded text with page breaks
\OuterFrameSep=\skip51
\fb@frw=\dimen152
\fb@frh=\dimen153
\FrameRule=\dimen154
\FrameSep=\dimen155
)
(D:\OfficeSoftware\MikTex\tex/latex/float\float.sty
Package: float 2001/11/08 v1.3d Float enhancements (AL)
\c@float@type=\count287
\float@exts=\toks19
\float@box=\box57
\@float@everytoks=\toks20
\@floatcapt=\box58
)
\minted@appexistsfile=\read3
\minted@bgbox=\box59
\minted@code=\write4
\c@minted@FancyVerbLineTemp=\count288
\c@minted@pygmentizecounter=\count289
\@float@every@listing=\toks21
\c@listing=\count290
)
(D:\OfficeSoftware\MikTex\tex/latex/xcolor\xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2023/11/15 v3.01 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(D:\OfficeSoftware\MikTex\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: xetex.def on input line 274.

(D:\OfficeSoftware\MikTex\tex/latex/graphics-def\xetex.def
File: xetex.def 2022/09/22 v5.0n Graphics/color driver for xetex
)
(D:\OfficeSoftware\MikTex\tex/latex/graphics\mathcolor.ltx)
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1350.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1366.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1372.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1373.
)
runsystem(for ^%i in (pygmentize.exe pygmentize.bat pygmentize.cmd) do set > te
st.aex <nul: /p x=^%~$PATH:i>> test.aex)...executed.

runsystem(del test.aex)...executed.


(D:\OfficeSoftware\MikTex\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-xetex.def
File: l3backend-xetex.def 2024-01-04 L3 backend support: XeTeX
\g__graphics_track_int=\count291
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box60
\g__pdf_backend_object_int=\count292
\g__pdf_backend_annotation_int=\count293
\g__pdf_backend_link_int=\count294
)
No file test.aux.
\openout1 = `test.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for TS1+cmr on input line 3
.
(D:\OfficeSoftware\MikTex\tex/latex/base\ts1cmr.fd
File: ts1cmr.fd 2023/04/13 v2.5m Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
\openout3 = `test.pyg'.

runsystem(pygmentize -S default -f latex -P commandprefix=PYG > test.out.pyg)..
.executed.

 (test.out.pyg)
runsystem(pygmentize -l "python" -f latex -P commandprefix=PYG -F tokenmerge -P
 stripnl="False" -o test.out.pyg test.pyg)...executed.


(test.out.pyg) [1

] (test.aux)
 ***********
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-01-04>
 ***********
runsystem(del test.pyg)...executed.

runsystem(del test.out.pyg)...executed.

 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 5028 strings out of 409616
 96945 string characters out of 5778052
 1918191 words of memory out of 5000000
 27102 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 558077 words of font info for 37 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1348 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 74i,5n,81p,268b,207s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s

Output written on test.pdf (1 page).
```

I compared the log files of XeLaTeX and PdfLaTeX, the main difference is:

```
(D:\OfficeSoftware\MikTex\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2024-01-04 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count295
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box60
) (test.aux)
\openout1 = `test.aux'.
```

And XeLaTex's

```
(D:\OfficeSoftware\MikTex\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-xetex.def
File: l3backend-xetex.def 2024-01-04 L3 backend support: XeTeX
\g__graphics_track_int=\count291
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box60
\g__pdf_backend_object_int=\count292
\g__pdf_backend_annotation_int=\count293
\g__pdf_backend_link_int=\count294
)
No file test.aux.
\openout1 = `test.aux'.
```

Full content shown after the command line `"xelatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape test.tex"` was executed:

```
I:\test>xelatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape test.tex
xelatex: security risk: running with elevated privileges
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999995 (MiKTeX 24.1) (preloaded format=xelatex.fmt)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(test.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-01-04>
(D:\OfficeSoftware\MikTex\tex/latex/base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(D:\OfficeSoftware\MikTex\tex/latex/base\size10.clo))
(D:\OfficeSoftware\MikTex\tex/latex/minted\minted.sty
(D:\OfficeSoftware\MikTex\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty)
(D:\OfficeSoftware\MikTex\tex/latex/kvoptions\kvoptions.sty
(D:\OfficeSoftware\MikTex\tex/generic/ltxcmds\ltxcmds.sty)
(D:\OfficeSoftware\MikTex\tex/latex/kvsetkeys\kvsetkeys.sty))
(D:\OfficeSoftware\MikTex\tex/latex/fvextra\fvextra.sty
(D:\OfficeSoftware\MikTex\tex/latex/etoolbox\etoolbox.sty)
(D:\OfficeSoftware\MikTex\tex/latex/fancyvrb\fancyvrb.sty)
(D:\OfficeSoftware\MikTex\tex/latex/upquote\upquote.sty
(D:\OfficeSoftware\MikTex\tex/latex/base\textcomp.sty))
(D:\OfficeSoftware\MikTex\tex/latex/lineno\lineno.sty))
(D:\OfficeSoftware\MikTex\tex/latex/base\ifthen.sty)
(D:\OfficeSoftware\MikTex\tex/latex/tools\shellesc.sty)
(D:\OfficeSoftware\MikTex\tex/latex/ifplatform\ifplatform.sty
(D:\OfficeSoftware\MikTex\tex/generic/pdftexcmds\pdftexcmds.sty
(D:\OfficeSoftware\MikTex\tex/generic/infwarerr\infwarerr.sty)
(D:\OfficeSoftware\MikTex\tex/generic/iftex\iftex.sty))
(D:\OfficeSoftware\MikTex\tex/generic/catchfile\catchfile.sty
(D:\OfficeSoftware\MikTex\tex/generic/etexcmds\etexcmds.sty))
(D:\OfficeSoftware\MikTex\tex/generic/iftex\ifluatex.sty))
(D:\OfficeSoftware\MikTex\tex/latex/xstring\xstring.sty
(D:\OfficeSoftware\MikTex\tex/generic/xstring\xstring.tex))
(D:\OfficeSoftware\MikTex\tex/latex/framed\framed.sty)
(D:\OfficeSoftware\MikTex\tex/latex/float\float.sty))
(D:\OfficeSoftware\MikTex\tex/latex/xcolor\xcolor.sty
(D:\OfficeSoftware\MikTex\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\color.cfg)
(D:\OfficeSoftware\MikTex\tex/latex/graphics-def\xetex.def)
(D:\OfficeSoftware\MikTex\tex/latex/graphics\mathcolor.ltx))
I:\test>set  /p x=C:\Program Files\Python312\Scripts\pygmentize.exe 0<nul: 1>>test.aex

I:\test>set  /p x= 0<nul: 1>>test.aex

I:\test>set  /p x= 0<nul: 1>>test.aex
        1 file(s) copied.

(D:\OfficeSoftware\MikTex\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-xetex.def) (test.aux)
(D:\OfficeSoftware\MikTex\tex/latex/base\ts1cmr.fd) (test.out.pyg)Error: Invalid value 'False -o test.out.pyg test.pyg' for option stripnl; use 1/0, yes/no, true/false, on/off

(test.out.pyg) [1] (test.aux)miktex-dvipdfmx: security risk: running with elevated privileges
        1 file(s) copied.
        1 file(s) copied.
 )
(see the transcript file for additional information)
Output written on test.pdf (1 page).
SyncTeX written on test.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on test.log.

I:\test>
```

For the error meassage `"Error: Invalid value 'False -o test.out.pyg test.pyg' for option stripnl; use 1/0, yes/no, true/false, on/off"`, will it be that somehow the Pygments option `"stripnl=False"` is not correctly separated from `"-o test.out.pyg test.pyg"`?

Then, I commented out the line `\setminted{stripnl=false}` in `minted.sty`, PdfLaTeX still works, but XeLaTeX prompts a new error that reads `Error: no lexer for alias 'python -f latex -P commandprefix=PYG -F tokenmerge -o test.out.pyg test.pyg' found`. Getting more confused now！

【Solution】 I just update the whole MikTeX, it works now. It seems that last MikTeX version has some bugs, though I cannot locate it. If anyone encounters similar problem, you should try updating MikTeX.

Comment: It works fine with XeLaTeX for me on TeX Live. Post the log file. I used double hyphens before the options, but that's presumably irrelevant. It would tell you if it was ignoring an option.

Comment: @cfr  double hyphens before the options doesn't help either

Comment: @Neymar87 This package needs to install `pygments`, do you install it?

Comment: @MadyYuvi Yep, I've had pygments installed, and PdfLaTeX output demonstrates that it works. I just cannot work with XeLaTeX, it's really weird.

Comment: @Neymar87 Did you try with `-shell-escape` ?

Comment: @MadyYuvi Yes, I did, as mentioned in my post.

Comment: works ok here. I have a bit newer l3kernel but beside this, there is not much difference, only at the end you have a warning less, that could mean that the pyg file is empty. You could try `\renewcommand{\DeleteFile}[2][]{\IfFileExists{#2}{\ShellEscape{copy #2 xx#2}\ShellEscape{del #2}}{}}` and then check the pyg files starting with `xx`.

Comment: Maybe TexMaker is the problem. You could try to compile the document from the command line, just with `xelatex --shell-escape test.tex`, and see if it works there and/or if you get more meaningful messages in the terminal itself or in the log file.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for the suggestion! Both xxtest.aex and xxtest.pyg are 1KB, and xxtest.out.pyg is 7KB.

Comment: @Marijn Unfortunately,  same result and same log content for the command line method.

Comment: Please copy-paste errors and do not include images of either code or messages. Images are more difficult to work with and impossible for screen reading software (unless you repeat the error in alt text, but then you might as well just drop the image).

Comment: @cfr updated. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I'm not sure it is the separation that's the problem; it's might be the use of `False` rather than `false`. Or both. It almost looks as if something like `stripnl="False -o ..."` is getting in there. But I know nothing about how Windows handles command line options.

Comment: @cfr It's not the problem of "False" and "false", I changed the `minted.sty` line `\setminted{stripnl=false}` with both `False` and `false`, the error is still the same. Since PdfLaTeX deals with it smoothly, I doubt some code in XeLaTeX handles the command line wrongly in Windows.

Comment: @Neymar87 Well *something* is parsing the command line wrongly because it is not seeing `-o` as a new option, but treating it as part of the value passed to the previous one. Does it work in LuaLaTeX?

Comment: @cfr It works both for PdfLateX and LaTeX, but I haven't tried it with LuaLaTeX because this LuaLaTeX isn't rightly set up right now.

Comment: A shot in the darkness: Have you tried with latexmk and xelatex flag?

Comment: @Mane32 Sorry, I don't understand your suggestion, can you elaborate it?

Comment: You can configure texmaker to use pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, etc. Have you tried using `latexmk --xelatex --shell-escape -synctex=1 %.tex`?

Comment: @Mane32 Thanks for the tip. I just update the whole MikTeX, it works now. It seems that last MikTeX version has some bugs, though I cannot locate it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved by updating MikTeX without identifying the source of the problem and is unlikely to be of help to a wider audience.

Comment: @cfr How to close this question? Or I just delete it?

Comment: @Neymar87 I voted to close already. Just give it time to get the votes :).

Comment: @cfr Is there a particular advantage in voting to close?
● possible advantage: it won't show up in unanswered question list (do we have an unanswered question list?)
● possible disadvantage: if someone go through MikTeX changelog and can point out what is the bug, it would be useful information and could be put in an answer

Comment: @user202729 Well, (1) the OP requested it be closed. (2) Closing follows what I think is fairly common practice on this site. That is, questions which don't provide enough information to be answered typically get closed, especially if solved in comments. (The lack of information may be due to a poor question or, as here, not.) (3) I believe it is site policy to close questions which are due to outdated software. (4) There is not generally much point in identifying bugs which have already been fixed.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because each one of the 4 reasons cfr mentions in the (today) last comment is a valid enough.